# increate nodebb/nginx request per second

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nodebb

i configured a server with nodebb (nodejs) and nginx as a proxy.
I'm populating nodebb database using a module accepted http request.

I run 100 request per time, and after ~56 second al requeste completed.

To decrease the delay, i resize the cloud server (digitalocean droplet) to 64gb ram 20cpu, but notting change.
I'm a newbie with nginx and nodebb, but i think there is some limit on nginx or nodebb configuration, is it right, or is there some other issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to decrease the delay you'll probably want to scale out horizontally to use all of the CPU cores, since NodeBB will by default listen on only one.

Take a look at the scaling docs here:

## https://docs.nodebb.org/configuring/scaling/

... namely, the "clustering" bit.